# how to center the image and place text on right bottom corner of the image with a rounded text

Tags: css, user-interface, frontend, tailwind-css

```
 <div className="relative">
          <img className="mx-auto rounded-lg" src={imageURL} alt="" />
          <div className="absolute bottom-0 right-0 h-16 w-16 rounded-full bg-red-500">
            Book a Ticket
          </div>
        </div>
```

This is a tailwind css code. How can I make center the image and the place the div with a Book Ticket text on the right bottom of the Image? and then I want to make the text inside the div get rounded inside the div. ?

The outer div is taking full width so the inner div getting placed at the right most side of the screen. if we do the outer div inline-block . the mx-auto doesn't work anymore now our image is not centered anymore.

what do we do ?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Thanks new learning : ) . I use github co-pilot so it gives a suggestion. and I use it. I never noticed that.. Thnaks alot for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to add the flex class and uses `justify-center` and `items-center` to horizontally and vertically center its contents.

Also the book a ticket part div now has an additional flex `justify-center` `items-center` class. This will center the text both horizontally and vertically within the div.

The text inside book a ticket div is wrapped in a span element with the `rounded-full` class. This will make the text appear rounded inside the circular div.

```
<div className="relative flex justify-center items-center">
  <img className="mx-auto rounded-lg" src={imageURL} alt="" />
  <div className="absolute bottom-0 right-0 h-16 w-16 rounded-full bg-red-500 flex justify-center items-center">
    <span className="rounded-full">Book a Ticket</span>
  </div>
</div>
```